# A decision about "or" and "asterisk"

Tags: regex

I'm writing a program that evaluates **regular expressions**.

```
Does (a|b)* = (a*|b*)?
```

When I evaluate the **regex** if this is true then it would help me evaluate a regex simpler.

Comment: You can check on regex101.com if those regex are the same.

Comment: They are non-equivalent regular expressions. Consider these inputs: `ba` and `aa` - which matches what?

Comment: I tried regex101.com. For (a*|b*) it didn't recognize a string of b's but did recognize a string of a's. Don't know what gives there.

Comment: Confirmed. Regex101 does not handle the second regex properly. All strings with b's and no a's (or vice versa) are part of that language.

Comment: A good tester is here : https://www.myregextester.com/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not equivalent regexes. Consider the string "aaaaab." It would be in the language defined by the first regex, but not by the second.

The reason for such is that (a|b)* can repeat the sub-regex, (a|b), zero or more times, while (a*|b*) can only repeat itself once.

To make it even clearer, the second language is made of strings containing only a's or only b's (or nothing), but not strings containing a's and b's.

This is the case because the Kleene star operator (*) stands for "zero or more of the item to the left." In the case of the former regex, the item to the left is the expression that includes the parenthesis. In the latter, the items to the left are "a" and "b." However, The | (or) operator means you get to pick a* or b*, but not both.

If we want to go all in on this one, the language defined by the second regex is actually a subset of the language defined by the first.

Feel free to ask if you'd like some more detail.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that explanation. It's what I was thinking.

Comment: Does (a*|b*)* = (a|b)*?

Comment: Well, what do you think? Can you construct the same languages with both of those regexes? What can you make with the former that you can't make with the latter?